# get json data from http api and display one value only?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to fetch this: https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=CAD&symbols=USD

which gives this in the browser:

```
{"rates":{"USD":0.7471190781},"base":"CAD","date":"2020-09-28"}
```

in a simple html page, I just want to display the value, in this case:

```
0.7471190781
```

Is there a simple way to do this in html/js?
thx

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: "Is there a simple way to do this in html/js?" Yes, yes there is but this is not a code writing service.

Comment: im aware its not a code writing service. I dont need to learn html. I'm just looking to do this simple on my web server to update excel sheets I have. ssc-hrep3's answer works perfect for me. if someone doesn't want to help me I believe they arent required to respond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply use `fetch()`. Then, you can add it to the DOM with e.g. `document.getElementById()`. Make sure, that you are targeting a browser where `fetch()` is working (no IE support; see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)).

```js
fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=CAD&symbols=USD')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    document.getElementById('test').innerText = data.rates.USD;
  });
```

```html
<div id="test">no value</div>
```

Comment: thank you. works great. really appreciate it. And appreciate you not being mean about me asking. :)  community here seems quite hostile.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch it with the javascript fetch API

```js
const res = await fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=CAD&symbols=USD');
const json = await res.json();
const USD = json.rates.USD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a ajax function?
in your html file:

```js
function updateStat(){
      $.ajax({url: 'routeName'}).done(function (data){
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#spanId').html(data.rates.USD);
      });
    }
    updateStat();
```

then in your index.js:

```js
const bot = require("fileName");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.get('routeName', (req, res) => {
    bot.data(function(data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

and in your other file (used to post json data to route):

```js
module.exports.data = function(callback) {
    var jsonArr = {
      "name": data,
      "name": data // Just an example
    }
    callback(jsonArr);
}
```

**These functions have been built for a node app**